# Extract String for specific characters SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, patindex

Trying to extract specific string from a varchar column in SQL Server. And then from that string I need the last 4 digits only.

I tried `substring` & `patindex` but can't figure out how to get the last 4 digits.

This was one attempt but it only returns the first part of the text:

```sql
SUBSTRING([column], (PATINDEX('%ID0%-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',[column])),9)
```

Here's some sample data:

```
Brian Larry, Hays Hill XX, ID007370, Option code - 0123 4567, AAA - XX
ID007366 - Dave Jones - XX - Option Code 0121 9999
ID00 7120  Brian Smith XX  Branded company
ID07113 Gary Barnes  - LLL 0123 9111 AAA LLL
ID00 7120  Charles Old XX   Recall operation
ID0007439 - Kerry Hill - Maidstone XX - Option Code 0124 234 BBB XX
ID006817 Paul George Jackson 1234 8464 AAA Recall operation
```

I need to extract the `ID00000` number, but then only return the last 4 digits. So for `ID007370`, I only want to return `7370`. The ID numbers can vary in length.

Comment: SQL Server is not your "friend" for this task; string manipulation is *not* its strong point. The fact you have inconsistent formats, different delimiters, *inconsistent* delimiters (I'm looking at you Gary), and varying lengths for the ID only makes that worse. Really you should be normalising the data before it ever hits your SQL layer.

Comment: Tell me about it :)

Comment: To make matters worse, the `ID` values do not even always appear in the same place within the string.  Even with full regex support, this is a tall task.  Fix your data before bringing it into SQL Server.

Comment: You *need* to go back to the source here; what ever is creating this awful data needs to be addressed. The row containing Gary Barnes is honestly *awful*; there's no defined delimiter. It can't be a single whitespace because then `Gary` and `Barnes` are different columns, but then it can't be a hyphen (`-`) because then you have a *single* column value `ID07113 Gary Barnes`. Paul George has a similar problem, in that white space is both a delimiter and inside the name. The data is terrible; that is the problem that needs to be addressed. Fix that and getting the ID becomes trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this looks to be working:

```sql
SELECT  RIGHT(SUBSTRING(string_nonspace, y.start, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', STUFF(string_nonspace, 1, start + 1, '')) + 1), 4)
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'Brian Larry, Hays Hill XX, ID007370, Option code - 0123 4567, AAA - XX')
    ,   (N'ID007366 - Dave Jones - XX - Option Code 0121 9999')
    ,   (N'ID00 7120  Brian Smith XX  Branded company')
    ,   (N'ID07113 Gary Barnes  - LLL 0123 9111 AAA LLL')
    ,   (N'ID00 7120  Charles Old XX   Recall operation')
    ,   (N'ID0007439 - Kerry Hill - Maidstone XX - Option Code 0124 234 BBB XX')
    ,   (N'ID006817 Paul George Jackson 1234 8464 AAA Recall operation')
) t (col1)
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  replace(col1, ' ', '') AS string_nonspace
    ) x
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  PATINDEX('%ID[0-9]%', string_nonspace) AS start
    ) y
```

Output:

| ID | string_nonspace |
| --- | --- |
| 7370 | BrianLarry,HaysHillXX,ID007370,Optioncode-01234567,AAA-XX |
| 7366 | ID007366-DaveJones-XX-OptionCode01219999 |
| 7120 | ID007120BrianSmithXXBrandedcompany |
| 7113 | ID07113GaryBarnes-LLL01239111AAALLL |
| 7120 | ID007120CharlesOldXXRecalloperation |
| 7439 | ID0007439-KerryHill-MaidstoneXX-OptionCode0124234BBBXX |
| 6817 | ID006817PaulGeorgeJackson12348464AAARecalloperation |

I remove spaces and then find starting position by `PATINDEX('%ID[0-9]%'`. Then i clip the string so ID-part is removed, and then search for first non-number value. When that done, you can do a SUBSTRING between start and the first non-number value. Finally, `RIGHT(..., 4)` gets the last four characters.

Of course this code will fail on many malformed strings, but them the breaks, the in-data kinda "blowers"

Comment: This is working for me! Thanks a lot siggemannen, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Although SQL is not that friendly when it comes to string extractions, you can Try this :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([column], LEN([column]) - 4, 4)
FROM [table];
```

This query will first find the length of the string in the [column] field using the LEN() function. Then, it will use the SUBSTRING() function to extract the last 4 characters of the string, starting at the length of the string minus 4. You can also use the following query to extract the last 4 digits of the ID00000 number, even if the ID number varies in length:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([column], PATINDEX('%ID0%-%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', [column]) + 6, 4)
FROM [table];
```

This query will first use the **PATINDEX()** function to find the position of the first occurrence of the string ID0%- in the [column] field. Then, it will use the SUBSTRING() function to extract the last 4 characters of the string, starting at the position of the ID0%- string plus 6.

Answer (score -1):

**There is no solution** that guaranties you will have a correct result because you violate the 1FN which is the most evil thing to do...

Just have a look if you have a new row like this one :

```
insert into Sample (SampleString)
values ('Brian Larry, LUCID007700880099 Hays Hill XX, ID007370, Option code - 0123 4567, AAA - XX')
```

Or this one :

```
insert into Sample (SampleString)
values ('Brian LUCID0AZ, Hays Hill XX, ID007370, Option code - 0123 4567, AAA - XX')
```